# my slideshow isn't working and my footer is out of place

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, footer

Please be patient with me, although I have an associate's degree I'm feeling very lost right now. still a newbie as far as I'm concerned. I have a 2 column layout and that isn't set up right I'm sure because my margin for the right column seems way out of whack. I have a slideshow on each side. Neither of my slideshows are working. They are just showing the last picture. Also, my footer is behind my slideshows instead of under them. I've tried adding and removing a container div both including and excluding the footer but neither seem to place it in the right spot. I used code I used before for a different project for the slideshows but it's not responding the same way here. My slideshow functions have no name because the last time I used them they only worked without names. I know several variables aren't defined but again, last time it worked without that. I'm not sure specifically how I need to define them. I'm sure I'm overlooking something small but I've walked away several times and can't find it. here's the code below, css, html and js...

```
/*footer*/
.footer {
margin: 10px;
padding: 5px;
width: 100%;
float: center;
border-top: dashed #bcbaba 3px;
}

/*page container*/
#container {
width: 1024px;
height: auto;
margin: 5px;
}

.left {
width: 506px;
float: left;
}

.right {
margin-left: 900px;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}


<div class="container">

<!--Slideshow of created work-->    
<div id="sites" class="left">
<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
<img id="bca" class="slide" src="../images/websites/bca/bcass.jpg" 
alt="Billie's Custom Abstracs"/>
<img id="bw" class="slide" src="../images/websites/bw/bwss.jpg" 
alt="Bellwood Museum"/>
<img id="sej" class="slide" src="../images/websites/sej/sejss1.jpg" 
alt="self esteem journal" />
<img id="sej1" class="slide" src="../images/websites/sej/sejss3.jpg" 
alt="meditation script" />
</div>
</div>

<div id="art" class="right">
<div id="slideshow1" class="slideshow1">
<img id="cbv1" class="slide1" src="../images/book/vol1/Abstracts and Fun 
V1_Page_02.jpg" alt="coloring book volume 1"/>
<img id="cbv2" class="slide1" src="../images/book/vol2/pg 0.jpg" 
alt="coloring book volume 2"/>
<img id="ap" class="slide1" src="../images/art/paintings/bluesnow.jpg" 
alt="blue snow painting"/>
<img id="wd"class="slide1" src="../images/art/trinkets/lbh1.jpg" alt="wooden 
trinkets"/>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<!--Footer-->
<div id="footer">
<p><b>Billie Cochell </b><br> phone <br> <a 
href="mailto:billiespages@gmail.com">billiespages@gmail.com</a>
    <br> <a 
href="mailto:billie.child79@gmail.com">billie.child79@gmail.com</a>
    </p>
    <br>
</div>

//Home Page/Slideshow//

(function ($) {

var slideshow = (function () {
        var counter = 0;
        i,
            j,
            slides = $("#slideshow .slide");
            slidesLen = slides.length - 1;
        for (i = 0, j = 9999; i < slides.length; i += 1, j -= 1) {
            $(slides[1]).css("z-index", j);
        }
        return {
            startSlideshow: function () {
                window.setInterval (function () {
                    if (counter === 0) {
                        slides.eq(counter).fadeOut();
                        counter += 1;
                    } else if (counter === slidesLen) {
                        counter = 0;
                        slides.eq(counter).fadeIn(function(){
                            slides.fadeIn();
                        });
                    } else {
                        slides.eq(counter).fadeOut ();
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                }, 7000);
            }
        };
    }());
    slideshow.startSlideshow();
}(jQuery));

                  (function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var slideshow2 = (function () {
        var counter = 0;
        i,
            j,
            slides = $("#slideshow1 .slide1");
            slidesLen = slides.length - 1;
        for (i = 0, j = 9999; i < slides.length; i += 1, j -= 1) {
            $(slides[1]).css("z-index", j);
        }
        return {
            startSlideshow: function () {
                window.setInterval (function () {
                    if (counter === 0) {
                        slides.eq(counter).fadeOut();
                        counter += 1;
                    } else if (counter === slidesLen) {
                        counter = 0;
                        slides.eq(counter).fadeIn(function(){
                            slides.fadeIn();
                        });
                    } else {
                        slides.eq(counter).fadeOut ();
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                }, 7000);
            }
        };
    }());
    slideshow2.startSlideshow();
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that before the  there's an unnecessary closing  and I think every div id should be closed with  rather than > because id is used for one element

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've run into a bit of css/javascript troubles.
There are a lot of different ways to accomplish a slideshow, so I wanted to link you to some examples/tutorials here, in case you're interested:

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-build-javascript-slideshow/
- https://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/dImly

There are also cookie cutter and out of the box options:

- http://wowslider.com/javascript-slideshow-quiet-rotate-demo.html
- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

There are loads more, these are here are food for thought.

As for the code you've written:

First things first, you need to scope down your slideshow frame with some css.  You can accomplish this by setting a height/width for your left and right slideshows and setting overflow to none, so that everything outside of frame is hidden.

```
.container {
  width: 1024px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 460px;
  height: 506px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Then the images need to be positioned one on top of the other for the since you're using a fading effect instead of a position effect, so we want the images to all be in position already.

```
.left .slideshow img, .right .slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

For the javascript, we always want to fade an image out and fade another in, the only thing that changes is the counter, which we can accomplish with the following function:

```
function changeImage() {
      slides.eq(counter).fadeOut(1000);
      if (counter >= slidesLen) {
        counter = 0;
      } else {
        counter += 1;
      }
      slides.eq(counter).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

I've set up a codepen here, to illustrate this method: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bojNqK

I removed the closure structure you used before, since you want exactly the same functionality for both slideshows (therefore we can reuse the single function to produce two different contexts). If you have questions on the closure structure, this also might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures